# Inherited data member in generic class not visible in derived class unless prefixed with this->

Tags: c++, generics, inheritance, g++, visibility

I have encountered the following problem with someone else's code which presumably was compiling at some point. A base class is a generic container of a data member of type T. This data member is `protected` but is only visible in the derived class' overridden functions when prefixed with `this->`. The following simplified example replicates the problem on my machine and on the currently distributed version of MinGW included with code::blocks 12.11

`Base.h`

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

template <typename T>
class Base
{
   public:
    void set(T value);
    virtual void show() = 0;
   protected:
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
void Base<T>::set(T value)
{
   this->value = value;
}

#endif
```

`Derived.h`

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include <iostream>

#include "Base.h"

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
   public:
    virtual void show();
};

template <typename T>
void Derived<T>::show()
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

Compiling a `.cpp` file which uses `Derived.h` results in the following error on g++4.6.3:

> In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
>   Derived.h: In member function ‘virtual void Derived::show()’:
>   Derived.h:18:15: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope

However simply changing `std::cout << value << std::endl;` to `std::cout << this->value << std::endl;` fixes the problem. The same behaviour is observed even with data members which are not of type T.

Is this expected behaviour? I imagine not since the legacy code was definitely compiling at some point.

Comment: It is expected. Out of curiosity, which compiler was the legacy code compiling with?

Comment: Oh yes so it does, thanks. I can happily watch this question move towards being closed. I must have phrased my question oddly because none of the suggestions offered by stack overflow included that question or any of its other versions.

Comment: @juanchopanza I believe on one of the Visual Studio compilers although I am not certain.

Comment: I think VS is non-standard about the two-phase look-up, so it will pass some illegal code (and make other code behave in non-standard ways).